# CircleCI build fails when setting up add_ssh_keys config

Tags: flutter, circleci, circleci-2.0

We have a repository which now draws from a private repository for a particular component.
A BitBucket SSH key is required to get access to this.

It is a Flutter app and the private repo reference in `pubspec.yaml` looks like this:

```yaml
  our_private_api-repo:
    git:
      url: git@bitbucket.org:our_org/our-private-api-repo.git
      ref: master
```

That all works just fine for local development.

Now I am trying to make the CircleCI deployment work.

I worked from [these instructions](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/add-ssh-key/), and [these](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/gh-bb-integration/#enable-your-project-to-check-out-additional-private-repositories), successfully adding my "**Additional SSH Key**".

The problem has arisen with the step where I am supposed to add reference to the ssh key, as per [the instructions](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/add-ssh-key/#adding-ssh-keys-to-a-job):

```
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "SO:ME:FIN:G:ER:PR:IN:T"
```

I've got the correct fingerprint from the CircleCI backend, and I've put the lines in the correct place (just under the `steps` section for my job, but when I push this change, CircleCI now reports the following errors:

```
> # |   |   3. [#/jobs/my-job/steps/3/fingerprints] no subschema matched out of the total 2 subschemas
> # |   |   |   1. [#/jobs/my-job/steps/3/fingerprints] expected type: Mapping, found: Sequence
> # |   |   |   |   SCHEMA:
> # |   |   |   |     type:
> # |   |   |   |     - object
> # |   |   |   |     - string
> # |   |   |   |   INPUT:
> # |   |   |   |     - 84:1a:fe:etc..(this is not it exactly)..:31:0f
> # |   |   |   2. [#/jobs/my-job/steps/3/fingerprints] expected type: String, found: Sequence
> # |   |   |   |   SCHEMA:
> # |   |   |   |     type:
> # |   |   |   |     - object
> # |   |   |   |     - string
> # |   |   |   |   INPUT:
> # |   |   |   |     - 84:1a:fe:etc..(this is not it exactly)..:31:0f
```

The error goes away if I remove the add_ssh_keys/fingerprints/fingerprint lines.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to missing a tab in my `config.yml` file.

Changed:

```
      - add_ssh_keys:
        fingerprints:
          - "84:1a:fe:SO:ME:FIN:G:ER:PR:IN:T"
```

To:

```
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "84:1a:fe:SO:ME:FIN:G:ER:PR:IN:T"
```